# SQL Error when I try to apply promotion rule

Tags: mysql, magento-1.6

I'm trying to save a catalog price rule and getting the following SQL error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`MY_DB_NAME`.`catalogrule_group_website`, CONSTRAINT
>   `catalogrule_group_website_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_id`) REFERENCES
>   `catalogrule` (`rule_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

I was getting this error last night when I was trying to apply a different rule, but it went away and the rule was applied after I reindexed (which may or may not be related).

I tried reindexing a few times today too, no dice. I consistently get this error when I try to apply any rule(s).

I'm not completely SQL ignorant, but am having trouble even beginning to debug. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

On version 1.6.1

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key constraint is there to help with data integrity. They normally fail if you are trying to update one table but do not update a linked table. If you look at the foreign key constraint it will tell you what the linked table is and what value it expects...